# How should I display images from the internet?

Tags: android, thumbnails

I am working on an app that keeps track of who you lended your book to, and I want to add an image feature, so that users can see thumbnails of each book in the list. I can get images via the google books api, but then I have two options. One is downloading the image and storing it on the users device, which means more storage space, but then I don't need to download the images every time the user enters the application. Second option is the opposite, not storing on the device so less storage space but more internet usage. What should I do?

Comment: Both options still require that image to be transferred to the user's device. Perhaps your dilemma is geared more towards caching the image on the user's device vs. downloading it everytime? Images (particularly thumbnails) don't take much space, and I would opt for caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a good 3rd party image loading framework, for example [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It implements all the best practices of image loading on Android, including asynchronous loading and caching.

Comment: That's really not an answer to the question. It's a good recommendation, but should have been a comment.